# What objects are available in jjs?

Tags: javascript, nashorn, jjs

When I am running Javascript in a browser I have the document object available to me.

For instance, I can do document.write() in javascript in a browser.

The document object is not available when I am running Javascript under the Java 8 Javascript engine jjs.

jjs is a the successor to Rhino and is delivered with Java 8 from Oracle.

What objects are available in jjs?
Where are they documented?

Comment: google "javascript jjs" and you get https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jjs.html

Comment: Those are command line arguments.  I am looking for the objects that I can use in the javascript.  I will clarify my question a bit more.

Comment: It would be appreciated if those who are voting to close would state their reason.  Then I might know how to reword the question.

Comment: Other than the standard JavaScript built-ins, there's really *nothing* available by default in the global scope. You can, however, create a global environment of your own design inside your Java code by explicitly exposing APIs through the `ScriptEngine` mechanism.

Comment: Also the "close" votes are based on the fact that this appears to be a request for documentation, and that's an established reason for questions to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document` won't be available when running via Nashorn/jjs since it doesn't have a DOM (like a javascript engine in a browser would), the same goes for `window`. In other aspects it should implement ECMASCRIPT 5.1 but according to this [blog post from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) it also lacks the console object which is a shame.

I haven't seen to much documentation about other stuff missing from the engine but there are a few pages which might be worth looking into over at the [OpenJDK Wiki for Nashorn](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Main).

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions  I will give you the win before they close this question.